# ChartJS large data range

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

I have a dataset which has large range between the largest and the smallest. My problem is that the smallest bar becomes invisible when the largest bar has too much data. Take a look at the screenshot below.

[image]

In the screenshot, the second, third, fifth and sixth bars all have **one** data point but they are being invisible. So my question is,

1) Is there anyway to make small data point visible for bar chart such as by setting min-height property on them?

2) If not, how can I make the chart so that hovering works on whole y-axis for a particular bar when the data is too small so that when I hover over the y-axis it shows label with data?

I've tried setting different styles on the bars to no avail.

Comment: @idleberg My requirement(from my boss) is that user should be able to see the value on y-axis as number, not logarithmic scale number.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't provided your code, I can only tell you to use a [logarithmic scale](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/logarithmic.html) for your chart.

See [this example](https://canvasjs.com/html5-javascript-chart-logarithmic-axis/) for reference:

```
var dataPoints = [
    { x: 1994, y: 25437639 },
    { x: 1995, y: 44866595 },
    { x: 1996, y: 77583866 },
    { x: 1997, y: 120992212 },
    { x: 1998, y: 188507628 },
    { x: 1999, y: 281537652 },
    { x: 2000, y: 414794957 },
    { x: 2001, y: 502292245 },
    { x: 2002, y: 665065014 },
    { x: 2003, y: 781435983 },
    { x: 2004, y: 913327771 },
    { x: 2005, y: 1030101289 },
    { x: 2006, y: 1162916818 },
    { x: 2007, y: 1373226988 },
    { x: 2008, y: 1575067520 },
    { x: 2009, y: 1766403814 },
    { x: 2010, y: 2023202974 },
    { x: 2011, y: 2231957359 },
    { x: 2012, y: 2494736248 },
    { x: 2013, y: 2728428107 },
    { x: 2014, y: 2956385569 },
    { x: 2015, y: 3185996155 },
    { x: 2016, y: 3424971237 }
];

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    zoomEnabled: true,
    theme: "dark2",
    title:{
        text: "Growth in Internet Users Globally"
    },
    axisX:{
        title: "Year",
        valueFormatString: "####",
        interval: 2
    },
    axisY:{
        logarithmic: true, //change it to false
        title: "Internet Users (Log)",
        titleFontColor: "#6D78AD",
        lineColor: "#6D78AD",
        gridThickness: 0,
        lineThickness: 1,
        includeZero: false,
        labelFormatter: addSymbols
    },
    axisY2:{
        title: "Internet Users",
        titleFontColor: "#51CDA0",
        logarithmic: false, //change it to true
        lineColor: "#51CDA0",
        gridThickness: 0,
        lineThickness: 1,
        labelFormatter: addSymbols
    },
    legend:{
        verticalAlign: "top",
        fontSize: 16,
        dockInsidePlotArea: true
    },
    data: [{
        type: "line",
        xValueFormatString: "####",
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "Log Scale",
        dataPoints: dataPoints
    },
    {
        type: "line",
        xValueFormatString: "####",
        axisYType: "secondary",
        showInLegend: true,
        name: "Linear Scale",
        dataPoints: dataPoints
    }]
});
```

Comment: My requirement(from my boss) is that user should be able to see the value on y-axis as number, not logarithmic scale number.